# GeoServer+GeoWebCache: request does not align to grid(s) 'EPSG:3407'

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I'm having a problem integrating GeoServer and GeoWebCache. When requesting the tiles, the geocaching result is always unsuccessful, and the error message I get is "geowebcache-miss-reason: request does not align to grid(s) 'EPSG:3407'.

I configured the gridset as in this

[image: screenshot]

and the layer bounds

[image: here].

If I generate the tiles manually using the Seeding tool, the generated tiles in the preview are always empty. If I use the preconfigured gridsets, it works as expected.

Any hints what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the problem was not on the Geoserver configuration, but in the client side. We were missing the `origin` parameter in the configuration of the custom SRS for Leaflet. This means that we were sending the wrong `bounds` to Geoserver, so Geocache couldn't find any matching gridset.

The solution was found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/brucecrevensten/a16a554ee1c64d9ac475a1468e94f508) (not mine). You can find more details about how to configure Leaflet+Geoserver+Geocache there.